# Keycloak API get each role for a specific user

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I try to access every role for the user `7b244fd8-5e1a-43af-9572-91d50784fda7` and found this code ([Keycloak User Roles missing in REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458138/keycloak-user-roles-missing-in-rest-api)):

```
GET /auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{user-uuid}/role-mappings/clients/{client-uuid}
```

This is why I try to make the following GET request (Bearer token correctly provided)

https://mywebsite.com/auth/admin/realms/master/users/7b244fd8-5e1a-43af-9572-91d50784fda7/role-mappings/clients/admin-cli

I get an `{"error": "Client not found" }` error.

I guess the "admin-cli" in my code is wrong, but this is the Client ID in the master realm. Is this the wrong id? How can I make the request to get all roles for a specific user working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get an {"error": "Client not found" } error.
>
> I guess the "admin-cli" in my code is wrong, but this is the Client ID
> in the master realm. Is this the wrong id? How can I make the request
> to get all roles for a specific user working?

You should use the ID of the client and not the client ID, which you can find on the url:

[image]

or via Rest Admin API:

```
GET /auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients?clientId=$CLIENT_ID
```

The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871), in that case the endpoint would be:

```
GET /admin/realms/{realm}/clients?clientId=$CLIENT_ID
```