# How to get user clientroles via REST-API from keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458138/keycloak-user-roles-missing-in-rest-api) especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48485431/411645).

According to the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) calling `GET /{realm}/users` gets you a [UserRepresentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation), which lists **clientRoles** as *optional*. That suggests, that it should be available in principle. But I do not know how I can leverage this.

I defined the endpoint as

```
const usersEndpoint = `${adminEndpoint}/realms/${realm}/users`;
```

Which should be correct.
Or am I reading something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about it the wrong way. You are able to get a list of users *having* a role or a group by:

`GET /{realm}/clients/{id}/roles/{role-name}/users`

resp.

`GET /{realm}/groups/{id}/members`.

In order to get the list of every user having which roles, you could iterate over all roles and request their repective users and merge it.

Or in my way, retrieving the list of users having a discrete role was enough to achieve what I wanted.